# what does mov dword ptr [rsp],eax ss:00000000`0011ddc0=00000060 mean?

Tags: assembly, windbg

showed up in my windbg session

```
wow64!Wow64EmulateAtlThunk+0x82ab:
00000000`736b5cbf 89442450        
         mov     dword ptr [rsp+50h],eax ss:00000000`0011ddc0=00000060
```

The second part of the `MOV` instruction **eax ss:00000000`0011ddc0=00000060** is quite confusing , how to interpret that ?

Comment: The debugger display indicates that location 111ddc0 has 32 bit content 60 hex. I didn't think that 64 bit mode used the ss register, just fs and gs for kernel usage, but I'm not sure about this. If ss is valid in 64 bit mode, then location 111ddc0 is relative to the mapped address based on ss.

Comment: I also had a look at your previous question. It seems that you're debugging the WOW64 layer of Windows. Perhaps that's required in your situation and you want to tell us that you're doing this by intention. Otherwise I'd suggest using a 32 bit debugger and looking at your code, not at Microsoft's code.

Comment: @rcgldr thanks for the comment. it seems that starting from SS is merely a comment, indicating the content of `dword ptr[rsp+50h]`, this is the debug result, to be confirmed.

Comment: @ThomasW. you can debug 32-bit code using 64-bit WinDbg using `.effmach x86` command

Comment: @EdChum: yes, as long as you don't want to load any extensions which require 32 bit (like SOS for 32 bit .NET).

Comment: @ThomasW. yes that is true and something to consider when determining which debugger to use initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dword ptr [rsp+50h]            , eax 
          ss:00000000`0011ddc0 = 00000060
```

ss: (Stack Segment) + rsp which is a 64bit register containing the current stack pointer + a fixed offset of 50h bytes which results in the address: 0x11ddc0, which currently contains: 0x60, is being assigned the value of eax register.

Comment: This does not mean that EAX has a value of 0x60, it means that the pointer at address 00000000`0011ddc0 currently contains the value 0x60. This instruction will overwrite that 0x60 with the current value of EAX.